# Class Cast exception while reading list from the file

Tags: java, serialization, casting

I am trying to save my subjects' state in a file. I have a list of subjects and i write them into the file. And i read the object back. But when I cast them into the list, i get class cast exception. I can see that the object is returned with all the values, but not able to cast them to list.

This is my list of subjects

```
private List<Subject> subjects;

FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("SaveFile", true);
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
        objectStream.writeObject(subjects);  
        objectStream.close();
```

This is the code where I am reading from the file

```
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("SaveFile");
        ObjectInputStream obStream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
        List<Subject> newSubjects = (List<Subject>)obStream.readObject();
```

Here is the exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List
>       at WebPageUpdateNotifier.Memento.getSavedData(Memento.java:43)
>       at WebPageUpdateNotifier.Client.run(Client.java:66)
>       at WebPageUpdateNotifierTest.ClientTest.testGetSubjectList(ClientTest.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Am I doing something wrong? I googled a lot but I found the syntax to be right.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `List<Subject> subjects;` Is the subjects variable instantiated, or null?

Comment: The value is set via the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're appending to the file, instead of writing new contents. If some object was previously serialized and then you serialize the `List<Subject>` by appending to the file, then upon de-serializing you will get the old object.

Try removing the boolean argument from the constructor call of `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("SaveFile");
```

instead of

```
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("SaveFile", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

As obStream.readObject(); returns an Object not a list of Object. You can prepare list as below:

```
List<Subject> newSubjects;
while ((obj = (Subject)objIn.readObject()) != null) {
     newSubjects.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: It returns whatever you wrote. He wrote a `List,` he gets back a `List.` Your code also relies on `null` being used as an end of list marker, which you didn't state, or else assumes that `readObject()` returns `null`  at end of stream, which it doesn't.